# What's the effect of not checking "store view specific" option for inline translation?

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, inline-translations

I have seen some tutorials about Magento inline translation feature and in all articles people have said that we have to mark that checkbox "Store view specific" but I never check it. Is there some "consequence" for that? What does that checkbox mean exactly?

Thank u